# Problem with Google task demo API

Tags: java, api, task

I've been following the launch of the Google Tasks API, and I was just to start playing with it, but I'm not be able to compile the first steps, I'm having an

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
```

Has somebody have a similar error or knows how can I fix this? I'm following the example in http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/tasks/v1/using.html#retrieving_task_lists

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java google API client library appears to have a [dependency](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Dependencies) on Google's [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) library. You'll need to add [guava-r09.jar](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/detail?name=guava-r09.zip) (contained in the linked zip file) and the jars for some or all of the other dependencies to your classpath. Or you could use Maven, in which case the dependencies would be taken care of for you.

Comment: I had to add, also all the *.jar from the dependency folder, thanks for the clue!